# User password getting hashed twice?

Tags: php, hash, passwords

I have created a profile update page where a user can update their email, password and profile image.

The problem that I am having is that when a user changes their password it will work for the first login. So  the user logs in and changes the profile image but not their password.

The script does not change the password but it does hash the password which is fine and the user can login. Now if the user decides that they want to change something else in their profile but again not the password, it hashes the already hashed password and the user cannot login.

I guess my question is there a way to check if the password is a hash then don't hash it just leave password as password?

I have included the code for the update page below below:

```
<?php
include('includes/header.php');
include('includes/db.php');
$hun = $_SESSION['user'];


   if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
   $origuserid = $_POST['user_id'];
   $pworg = $_POST['password'];

   $pw= password_hash($pworg,PASSWORD_DEFAULT,array('cost =>12'));


  
   //create uid for image title

   $email= filter_var($_POST['email'],FILTER_SANITIZE_EMAIL);
   $Atitle= $_POST['username'];
   $title= $Atitle;
   $imtitle = str_replace('"',"'",$title);
   $username = filter_var($title, FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
   $firstUid= abs( crc32( uniqid('',false) ) );
   $uid =$imtitle.substr($FirstUid,0,5);

}
   //move image file
   
   $orig_file= $_FILES['user_image']['tmp_name'];
   $ext= pathinfo($_FILES['user_image']['name'],PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
   $target_dir= 'userimage/';
   $bn=basename($_FILES['user_image']['name']);
   $destination = $target_dir.$uid.$bn;
   move_uploaded_file($orig_file, $destination);
   $impath= $destination;

   if(!file_exists($img)){    
  
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare("SELECT `user_image` FROM `users` WHERE `user_id`=:id"); 
      $stmt->bindValue(':id', $origuserid);
      $stmt->execute();
      $result = $stmt->fetchColumn();
      
      $Adestination=$result; // was going to do something here...
      $destination=$Adestination;
            
   }

   // submit to update query
   $isSuccess = $crud->profileupdate($userid, $email, $pw, $destination);
```

Comment: This script should never _get_ an already hashed password. This is a problem in the form you use to profile updates, not the processing script. Show us the form code.

Comment: If they're not changing their password, `$_POST['password']` should be empty. You should check for this, and skip the code that hashes it and updates that column.

Comment: Thank you  GrumpyCrouton and Barmar makes perfect sense to only update if there is something to update it with. One day when I grow up I will have this committed to memory! :)